# reading txt file into perl's hash

Tags: perl, file, memory, hash

Hej sharp minds!

I need to load text file into hash. One line is the key, next line is the value. And that repeats several million times. Any suggestions how to do it in the best way?

And how much memory the hash table would need if let's say key is 15 characters and value is 50 characters?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code should load the text file into the hash:

```
my %hash;

while (chomp(my $key = <DATA>)) {
    chomp(my $val = <DATA>);
    $hash{$key} = $val;
}
```

The memory overhead of the hash entries will depend on the architecture (32 vs. 64 bit) but should be on the order of a couple hundred bytes for the hash itself, and then about 30-60 bytes per key and value, plus the overhead of the key and value data types.  You can use [`Devel::Size`](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/Devel-Size-0.77/lib/Devel/Size.pm) to check it yourself.   Also [read this](http://codenode.com/perl-memory-usage/).

So in your example, on a 64-bit platform, a million entries should cost roughly:

136 for the hash

58 + 15 + 58 + 50 == 181 per key/value pair x 1,000,000

181MB for a million entries of the sizes you specified.

Comment: thanks for informative answer. was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: I get "Use of uninitialized value $key in chomp at ./test.pl line 16, <IN> line 10000." that's the last line of test file... I see way $key gets undef, but is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @iggy: You could wrap the code in a `no warnings "uninitialized"` pragma block, or separate the read (`<>`) from the `chomp` and check definedness of the key/value before continuing the loop.  This was just example code and would need fine tuning for your needs, of course...